# Translating an Excel concept into SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have the following range in Excel named `MyRange`:

[image]

This isn't a table by any means, it's more a collection of Variant values entered into cells. Excel makes it easy to sum these values doing `=SUM(B3:D6)` which gives `25`. Let's not go into the details of type checking or anything like that and just figure that sum will easily skip values that don't make sense.

If we were translating this concept into SQL, what would be the most natural way to do this? The few approaches that came to mind are (ignore type errors for now):

1. `MyRange` returns an array of values:

   ```
   -- myRangeAsList = [1,1,1,2, ...]
   SELECT SUM(elem) FROM UNNEST(myRangeAsList) AS r (elem);
   ```
2. `MyRange` returns a table-valued function of a single column (basically the opposite of a list):

   ```
    -- myRangeAsCol = (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL ...
    SELECT SUM(elem) FROM myRangeAsCol as r (elem);
   ```
3. Or, perhaps more 'correctly', return a 3-columned table such as:

   ```
    -- myRangeAsTable = (SELECT 1,1,1 UNION ALL SELECT 2,'other',2 UNION ALL ...
    SELECT SUM(a+b+c) FROM SELECT a FROM myRangeAsTable (a,b,c)
   ```

   Unfortunately, I think this makes things the most difficult to work with, as we now have to combine an unknown number of columns.

Perhaps returning a single column is the easiest of the above to work with, but even that takes a very simple concept -- `SUM(myRange)` and converts into something that is anything but that: `SELECT SUM(elem) FROM myRangeAsCol as r (elem)`.

Perhaps this could also just be rewritten to a function for convenience, for example:

[image]

Comment: I think, answer to `"what would be the most natural way to do this?"` depends on actual use case! can you clarify what your specific use case and input data

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant that's a tricky one -- I'd say "easiest for someone who knows excel" to do!

Comment: An Excel sheet is more similar to a flat file than to a table. For example, the rows of a relational table don't have inherent ordering. So that's a non-starter since a "range" doesn't make any sense in a table.

Comment: @TheImpaler I see, so maybe to reshape the question if you had to provide an interface for an Excel-range-like object to be useful if exposed to SQL, how would that object/method look?

Comment: To just get the sum of all elements any arbitrary way to store your values is good. Is the order of columns and rows significant in any way? *"Ignore type errors for now"* isn't an expedient approach as data types and possible input values matter a lot in a strictly typed environment like SQL (especially Postgres). Tell us more about your use case, which RDBMS and version you actually use, and what you primarily optimize for. Versatility, performance, storage, simplicity, ..?

Comment: What is your question again?

Answer (score 4):

Just possible direction to think

```
create temp function extract_values (input string) 
returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";
with myrangeastable as (
  select '1' a, '1' b, '1' c union all 
  select '2', 'other', '2' union all
  select 'true', '3', '3' union all
  select '4', '4', '4' 
)
select sum(safe_cast(value as float64)) range_sum
from myrangeastable t,
unnest(extract_values(to_json_string(t))) value
```

with output

[image]

Note: no columns explicitly used so should work for any sized range w/o any changes in code

Depends on specific use case, I think above can be wrapped into something more friendly  `for someone who knows excel to do`

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to pose, atomic, pure SQL principles that start with obvious items and goes to the more complicated ones. The intention is, all items can be used in any RDBS:

1. SQL is basically designed to query tabular data which has relations. (Hence the name is  Structured Query Language).
2. The range in excel is a table for SQL. (Yes you can have some other types in different DBs, but keep it simple so you can use the concept in different types of DBs.)
3. Now we accept a range in the excel is a table in a database. Then the next step is how to map columns and rows of an excel range to a DB table. It is straight forward. An excel range column is a column in DB. And a row is a row. So why is this a separate item? Because the main difference between the two is usually in DBs, adding new column is usually a pain, the DB tables are almost exclusively designed for new rows not for new columns. (But, of course there are methods to add new columns, and even there exists column based DBs, but these are out of the scope of this answer.)

**Items 2 and 3 in Excel and in a DB:**

[image: Items 2 and 3 in Excel]

```sql
/*
Item 2: Table
    the range in the excel is modeled as the below test_table
Item 3: Columns
    id keeps the excel row number
    b, c, d are the corresponding b, c, d columns of the excel
*/

create table test_table
(
    id integer,
    b varchar(20),
    c varchar(20),
    d varchar(20)
);


-- Item 3: Adding the rows in the DB
insert into test_table values (3 /* same as excel row number */ , '1', '1', '1');
insert into test_table values (4 /* same as excel row number */ , '2', 'other', '2');
insert into test_table values (5 /* same as excel row number */ , 'TRUE', '3', '3');
insert into test_table values (6 /* same as excel row number */ , '4', '4', '4');
```

4. Now we have similar structure. Then the first thing we want to do is to have equal number of rows between excel range and db table. At DB side this is called filtering and your tool is the `where` condition. `where` condition goes through all rows (or indexes for the sake of speed but this is beyond this answer's scope), and filters out which does not satisfy the test boolean logic in the condition. (So for example `where 1 = 1` is brings all rows because the condition is always `true` for all rows.
5. The next thing to do is to sum the related columns. For this purpose you have two options. To use `sum(column_a + column_b)` (row by row summation) or `sum(a) + sum(b)` (column by column summation). If we assume all the data are not null, then both gives the same output.

**Items 4 and 5 in Excel and in a DB:**

[image: Items 4 and 5 in Excel]

```sql
select sum(b + c + d) -- Item 5, first option: We sum row by row
    from test_table
    where id between 3 and 6; -- Item 4: We simple get all rows, because for all rows above the id are between 3 and 6, if we had another row with 7, it would be filtered out
+----------------+
| sum(b + c + d) |
+----------------+
|             25 |
+----------------+

select sum(b) + sum(c) + sum(d) -- Item 5, second option: We sum column by column
    from test_table
    where id between 3 and 6; -- Item 4: We simple get all rows, because for all rows above the id are between 3 and 6, if we had another row with 7, it would be filtered out
+--------------------------+
| sum(b) + sum(c) + sum(d) |
+--------------------------+
|                       25 |
+--------------------------+
```

6. At this point it is better to go one step further. In the excel you have got the "pivot table" structure. The corresponding structure at SQL is the powerful `group by` mechanics. The `group by` basically groups a table according to its condition and each group behaves like a sub-table. For example if you say `group by column_a` for a table, the values are grouped according to the values of the table.
7. SQL is so powerful that you can even filter the sub groups using `having` clauses, which acts same as `where` but works over the columns in `group by` or the functions over those columns.

**Items 6 and 7 in Excel and in a DB:**

[image: Items 6 and 7 in Excel]

```sql
-- Item 6: We can have group by clause to simulate a pivot table
insert into test_table values (7 /* same as excel row */ , '4', '2', '2');

select b, sum(d), min(d), max(d), avg(d)
    from test_table
    where id between 3 and 7
    group by b;
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| b    | sum(d) | min(d) | max(d) | avg(d) |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1    |      1 | 1      | 1      |      1 |
| 2    |      2 | 2      | 2      |      2 |
| TRUE |      3 | 3      | 3      |      3 |
| 4    |      6 | 2      | 4      |      3 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Beyond this point following are the details which are not directly related with the questions purpose:

- SQL has the ability for table joins (the relations). They can be thought like the VLOOKUP functionality in the Excel.
- The RDBSs have the indexing mechanisms to fetch the rows as quick as possible. (Where the RDBMSs start to go beyond the purpose of excel).
- The RDBSs keep huge amount of data (where excel the max rows are limited).
- Both RDBSMs and Excel can be used by most of frameworks as persistent data layer. But of course Excel is not the one you pick because its reason of existence is more on the presentation layer.

The excel file and the SQL used in this answer can be found in this github repo: https://github.com/MehmetKaplan/stackoverflow-72135212/

PS: I used SQL for more than 2 decades and then reduced using it and started to use Excel much frequently because of job changes. Each time I use Excel I still think of the DBs and  "relational algebra" which is the mathematical foundation of the RDBMSs.

Comment: thanks for this, but my question is why name the columns a-d ? For example what if the user has the data entirely transposed? Why not name it rows 3-6 instead of cols b-d -- it seems arbitrary? Also, if the user inserts a column in the spreadsheet would you have to update the names of all the columns, etc?

Comment: First I need to re-emphasise, for most RDBMSs the data grow “row by row”, not “column by column”. Even for excel, as you correctly put, if the data is growing in columns then there may be a problem modelling the data. Columns define the structure of the table, rows define the values, aka cell contents in the excel world. 
Of course one person may chose to grow its data horizontally (in a transposed manner) but in such rare cases still the modelling at the DB must be done as vertical growth. RDBMS chose to do so because this is the most usual approach. Think of a word document, you…

Comment: …almost always grow your document in portrait way.

Comment: On the other hand it has mathematical consequences also. You want to grow your data one dimensionally to keep the control. If a table grows in both column-wise and row-wise, you have to go visit previously inserted data and have a decision what would be the related values for those rows. 

One more point, the inner structure, how data is kept, is not necessarily sequential, representing horizontal (or vertical) growth. There are various methods like b-trees, hash tables, etc…

Comment: And coming back to your question, I named columns b, c, d to make an analogy with your example. Normally they should have their own column names, indicating what that column represents. Same logic with converting a range to a table in the Excel.

Comment: I guess we need to agree on the most fundamental concept, the item 1. SQL means “Structured Query Language”. So to use SQL properly your data should have a structure that can be queried, it is the table. 

So if you want to handle a range in an RDBMS, I would suggest you to think about first converting it to a table, in order to use SQL with its powers.

Answer (score 2):

So in *Snowflake*:

### Strings as input:

if you have your data in a "order" table represented by this CTE:
and the data was strings of comma separated values:

```
WITH data(raw) as (
select * from values
    ('null,null,null,null,null,null'),
    ('null,null,null,null,null,null'),
    ('null,1,1,1,null,null'),
    ('null,2, other,2,null,null'),
    ('null,true,3,3,null,null'),
    ('null,4,4,4,null,null')
)
```

this SQL will select the sub part, try parse it and sum the valid values:

```
select sum(nvl(try_to_double(r.value::text), try_to_number(r.value::text))) as sum_total
from data as d
    ,table(split_to_table(d.raw,',')) r
where r.index between 2 and 4 /* the column B,C,D filter */
    and r.seq between 3 and 6 /* the row 3-6 filter */
;
```

giving:

| SUM_TOTAL |
| --- |
| 25 |

### Arrays as input:

if you already have arrays.. here I am smash those strings into STRTOK_TO_ARRAY in the CTE to make me some arrays:

```
WITH data(_array) as (
select STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(column1, ',') from values
    ('null,null,null,null,null,null'),
    ('null,null,null,null,null,null'),
    ('null,1,1,1,null,null'),
    ('null,2, other,2,null,null'),
    ('null,true,3,3,null,null'),
    ('null,4,4,4,null,null')
)
```

thus again with almost the same SQL, but not the array indexes are 0 based, and I have used FLATTEN:

```
select sum(nvl(try_to_double(r.value::text), try_to_number(r.value::text))) as sum_total
from data as d
    ,table(flatten(input=>d._array)) r
where r.index between 1 and 3 /* the column B,C,D filter */
    and r.seq between 3 and 6 /* the row 3-6 filter */
;
```

gives:

| SUM_TOTAL |
| --- |
| 25 |

### With JSON driven data:

This time using semi-structured data, we can include the filter ranges with the data.. and some extra "out of bounds values just to show we are not just converting it all.

```
WITH data as (
    select parse_json('{ "col_from":2,
                      "col_to":4,
                      "row_from":3,
                      "row_to":6,
                      "data":[[101,102,null,104,null,null],
                   [null,null,null,null,null,null],
                   [null,1,1,1,null,null],
                   [null,2, "other",2,null,null],
                   [null,true,3,3,null,null],
                   [null,4,4,4,null,null]
                   ]}') as json 
)
select 
   sum(try_to_double(c.value::text)) as sum_total
from data as d
    ,table(flatten(input=>d.json:data)) r
    ,table(flatten(input=>r.value)) c
where r.index+1 between d.json:row_from::number and d.json:row_to::number 
  and c.index+1 between d.json:col_from::number and d.json:col_to::number
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using Snowflake scripting (Snowsight format) . This code can easily be wrapped as a stored procedure.

```
declare
    table_name := 'xl_concept';  -- input
    column_list := 'a,b,c';      -- input
    total resultset;             -- result output
    pos int := 0;                -- position for delimiter
    sql := '';                   -- sql to be generated
    col := '';                   -- individual column names
begin
    sql := 'select sum(';  -- initialize sql
    loop -- repeat until column list is empty
        col := replace(split_part(:column_list, ',', 1), ',', ''); -- get the column name
        pos := position(',' in :column_list); -- find the delimiter
        sql := sql || 'coalesce(try_to_number('|| col ||'),0)'; -- add to the sql
        if (pos > 0) then -- more columns in the column list
            sql := sql || ' + '; 
            column_list := right(:column_list, len(:column_list) - :pos); -- update column list
        else -- last entry in the columns list
            break;
        end if;
    end loop;
    sql := sql || ') total from ' || table_name||';'; -- finalize the sql
    total := (execute immediate :sql); -- run the sql and store total value
    return table(total); -- return total value
end;
```

only these two variables need to be set `table_name` and `column_list`

generates the following sql to sum up the values

`select sum(coalesce(try_to_number(a),0) + coalesce(try_to_number(b),0) + coalesce(try_to_number(c),0)) from xl_concept`

prep steps

```
create or replace temp table xl_concept (a varchar,b varchar,c varchar)
;
insert into xl_concept
with cte as (
  select '1' a, '1' b, '1' c union all 
  select '2', 'other', '2' union all
  select 'true', '3', '3' union all
  select '4', '4', '4' 
)
select * from cte
;
```

result for the run with no change

```
TOTAL
25
```

result after changing column list to  `column_list := 'a,c';`

```
TOTAL
17
```

Also, this can be enhanced setting `columns_list` to `*` and reading the column names from `information_schema.columns` to include all the columns from the table.

Answer (score 1):

In `PostgreSQL` regular expression can be used to filter non numeric values before `sum`

```sql
select sum(e::Numeric) from (
  select e 
    from unnest((Array[['1','2w','1.2e+4'],['-1','2.232','zz']])) as t(e) 
    where e  ~ '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$'
) a
```

expression for validating numeric value was taken from post [Return Just the Numeric Values from a PostgreSQL Database Column](https://database.guide/return-just-the-numeric-values-from-a-postgresql-database-column/)

More secure option is to define function as in [PostgreSQL alternative to SQL Servers try_cast function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203934/postgresql-alternative-to-sql-server-s-try-cast-function)

Function (simplified for this example):

```sql
create function try_cast_numeric(p_in text)
   returns Numeric
as
$$
begin
  begin
    return $1::Numeric;
  exception 
    when others then
       return 0;
  end;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Select

```sql
select 
  sum(try_cast_numeric(e)) 
from 
  unnest((Array[['1','2w','1.2e+4'],['-1','2.232','zz']])) as t(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most modern RDBMS support lateral joins and table value constructors. You can use them together to convert arbitrary columns to rows (3 columns per row become 3 rows with 1 column) then `sum`. In SQL server you would:

```
create table t (
    id int not null primary key identity,
    a  int,
    b  int,
    c  int
);

insert into t(a, b, c) values
(   1,    1, 1),
(   2, null, 2),
(null,    3, 3),
(   4,    4, 4);

select sum(value)
from t
cross apply (values
    (a),
    (b),
    (c)
) as x(value);
```

Below is the implementation of this concept in some popular RDBMS:

- [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f61aaf3ba91366b7aae4bea4570f180)
- [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aff576254143975985641b0c10edb03f)
- [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8bb41e098a5116d193c91fd2e68071e9)
- [Generic solution, ANSI SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=38c455b5ce6db67e5439d5728ef06760)
- [Unpivot solution, Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8bf95d0d18fc1047a8abe547df0153de)

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression to extract all number values from a row could be another option, I guess.

```sql
DECLARE rectangular_table ARRAY<STRUCT<A STRING, B STRING, C STRING>> DEFAULT [
  ('1', '1', '1'),  ('2', 'other', '2'), ('TRUE', '3', '3'), ('4', '4', '4')
];

SELECT SUM(SAFE_CAST(v AS FLOAT64)) AS `sum`
  FROM UNNEST(rectangular_table) t,
       UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r':"?([-0-9.]*)"?[,}]')) v
  
output:
+------+------+
| Row  | sum  |
+------+------+
|    1 | 25.0 |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE with a SELECT FROM VALUES

```
with xlary as
(
  select val from (values 
                   ('1')
                   ,('1')
                   ,('1')
                   ,('2')
                   ,('OTHER')
                   ,('2')
                   ,('TRUE')
                   ,('3')
                   ,('3')
                   ,('4')
                   ,('4')
                   ,('4')
                  ) as tbl (val)
)
select sum(try_cast(val as number)) from xlary;
```

[image: SnowSQL example]