# How to create view from list of columns names in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am trying to create a view from a list of columns from my Python code.

I found many way to create a view by specifying each colum as follows

```
"create view myview as select col1, col2 from mytable;"
```

but here i need to use a list of columns to create the view as follows

```
col_list=['col1','col2','col3']


query="""create view my_view as select {*col_list}from @mystage"""
```

Is this the right way to create a view from a list of columns?

Comment: You can create a Snowflake script to parse the list and construct your query, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72135212/translating-an-excel-concept-into-sql/72188012#72188012 as an example

Comment: Thanks @demircioglu for sharing this, however looking at your answer, it feel bit confusing on thinking how to apply the logic to create a view out of list columns.. can you give a alignment to my requirement

Answer (score 2):

Using string interpolation:

```
col_list=['col1','col2','col3']

query="""create view my_view as select {} 
from @mystage""".format(', '.join(str(x) for x in col_list))

print(query)
```

Output:

> create view my_view as select col1, col2, col3
>
> from @mystage

Warning:

Building SQL string could lead to SQL Injection if the input is not trusted/validated.